# Replace for loop such that non-empty rows are counted

Tags: excel, vba

This code takes entries from the Data sheet and pastes them onto the Calculate sheet with three rows between each entry.

I have to change the for loop to correspond to the number of non-empty entries.

```
Sub Paste()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 493
        Sheets("Data").Range("A2:J2").Offset(i - 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Calculate").Range("A2:J2").Offset((i - 1) * 4)
    Next
End Sub
```

I want the macro to count the number of entries that are NOT empty and execute the code accordingly.

Tried this code, but it does not work.

```
Sub CP()
    Dim x As Long: x = Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To (x - 1)
        If LenB(Sheets("Data").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value) > 0 Then
            Sheets("Data").Range("A2:J2").Offset(i - 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Calculate").Range("A2:J2").Offset((i - 1) * 4)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe what you meant by "it does not work"

Comment: "Runtime error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error"  stemming from the "Sheets...*4)" line

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the For i = 0 To (x - 1) to  For i = 1 To (x - 1). This way you can avoid the Offset.
If LenB(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0 Then

And then you can change the destination:
Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Calculate").Cells(i+3, 1)

it should work

Comment: Column A is pasted without three spaces in between each entry

Comment: have updated the code. you can increase the i when you specify +x. This will work only for column A. As you have Cells(i,1)

Comment: if you would like to copy range form A to J. you have to specify the range. Can make that if you would like to

Comment: Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(i, 1),cells(i,10).Copy

Comment: Sheets("Data").Range("A"&i&":J"&i).Copy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same in the second macro as in the first but do not know the exact number of rows (493 in the first), then you can correct the second macro easily.

The error is that .Cells uses 1-based indexing, while .Offset uses 0-based indexing. So if i = 0, then Offset((i-1)*4) will be Offset(-4), which means 4 cells above row 2 but there is no minus second row.

The correct code is therefore:

```
Sub CP()
    Dim x As Long: x = Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To x ' Changed
        If LenB(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0 Then ' Changed
            Sheets("Data").Range("A2:J2").Offset(i - 1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Calculate").Range("A2:J2").Offset((i - 1) * 4)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```